Variation of the Lagrangian expressed as a time derivative of a function
In chapter 4.5 of Jakob Schwichtenberg's Physics from Symmetry, he expresses the variation of the Lagrangian $L = L\left ( q, \dot{q}, t \right )$ with respect to the generalized coordinate $q$ as
$$\delta L = L\left ( q, \dot{q}, t \right ) - L \left ( q + \delta q, \dot{q} + \frac{d\delta q}{dt}, t \right )$$
He then says that letting $\delta L \neq 0$ is fine as long as the action is invariant under the variation:
$$\delta S = \int dt \delta L = 0 \tag{1}$$
He claims that $L$ can differ from another Lagrangian, say, $L^\prime$, by the time derivative of a function $G = G\left ( q, t \right )$. Let's say that
$$L^\prime = L + \frac{dG}{dt}$$
He then goes on to prove that the variation with respect to the new Lagrangian is equal to the variation of the action of the original Lagrangian, namely:
$$\delta S^\prime = \int dt \delta L^\prime = \int dt \delta L + \int dt \frac{d}{dt}\delta G = \delta S + \frac{\partial G}{\partial q}\delta q \Bigg|_\text{(endpoints)} = \delta S \tag{2}$$
where $\frac{\partial G}{\partial q}\delta q \Bigg|_\text{(endpoints)}$ is zero due to the vanishing variation $\delta q$ at the bounds of integration. This proves that $L$ and $L^\prime$ yield the same equations of motion. From this, he posits that the variation in $L$ can be expressed as
$$\delta L = \frac{dG}{dt}\tag{3}$$
implying that the Lagrangian can vary in this fashion while keeping $S$ invariant. However, inserting this expression into $\left ( 1 \right )$ yields
$$\delta S = \int dt \frac{dG}{dt} = G \Bigg|_{\text{(endpoints)}}\tag{4}$$
which is not necessarily zero since there was never any restriction imposed on $G$ to either vanish or have the same value at both integration bounds. Should the variation in $L$ be more accurately expressed as
$$\delta L =  \frac{d}{dt}\delta G$$
since it was readily shown in $\left ( 2 \right )$ that the above vanishes when integrated? I can only reason the original form in $\left ( \text{3} \right )$ if I literally interpret $\delta L$ as $\delta L = L^\prime - L$ which I have a hard time justifying since $\frac{d G}{d t}$ is not an infinitesimal, on top of what was shown in $\left ( 4 \right )$.
For what it's worth, I believe the form of $\left ( \text{3} \right )$ due to how it's used immediately after in the book, I just can't seem to justify its form. The only other reference I could find that has the variation of $L$ in this form is this webpage which likewise doesn't explain the form of $\delta L$.

Is it to prove Noether's theorem?

Yes, the specific subsection that I'm pulling from is titled "Noether’s Theorem for Particle Theories."


OP already seems aware that Ref. 1 on p. 102 implicitly is talking about 2 different types of (infinitesimal) variations:

i. Ordinary variations to derive EL equations. These do satisfy boundary conditions.

ii. Symmetry variations. These do not satisfy boundary conditions.


See also e.g. this related Phys.SE post.

Ref. 1. appears to use the fact that

i. the EL equations are not affected by a boundary term

to motivate

ii. the notion of a quasisymmetry

and goes on to prove Noether's first theorem for quasisymmetries.

Returning to OP's concrete calculation, it is perhaps helpful to say that the function $G$ should be viewed as part of the action in case (i) but not in case (ii).


References:

J. Schwichtenberg, Physics from Symmetry, 2nd edition, 2018; p. 102.


So, if I'm understanding this correctly, when the author proposes that $\delta L = \frac{dG}{dt}$, the variation of $L$ in this context is to be interpreted as a symmetry variation which means that we should not expect $\left ( 4 \right )$ to vanish, i.e., the boundary term that the action is invariant up to?

$\uparrow$ Right.

To build intuition, you can consider a 1D particle in a uniform force field (eg free fall) with the Lagrangian:
$$
L=\frac12\dot x^2-x
$$
and equation of motion:
$$
\ddot x+1=0
$$
The system is invariant by translation even if $L$ is not:
$$
\delta L=-\delta q=\frac d{dt} (-t\delta q)
$$
The corresponding conserved quantity predicted by Noether’s theorem is:
$$
Q=\dot q+t
$$
Another simple example is invariance by Galilean/relativstic boosts of a free particle.
Recall that for the variational principle, the value of the action $S$ is not physical. Only differences in the action of two paths with the same endpoints are physical, and establish the equations of motion. This is why if $\delta S$ is just a boundary term, it is independent of $q$, so the equations of motions are preserved. This property descends to the Lagrangian $L$ which is defined up to a total derivative.
In the previous example:
$$
\delta S=-T\delta q
$$
which is independent of the bulk trajectory $q$, which is why the equations of motion are unchanged.

I'm still having trouble convincing myself that a (constant) boundary term in $\delta S$ leaves the Euler-Lagrange equations invariant since $\delta S \neq 0$ is in direct conflict with Hamilton's principle. Is it correct to say that any non-zero variation in $S$ produced by a variation in $L$ that does not respect the bounds of integration (c.f. answer by @Qmechanic ) can be regarded as "effectively zero" in the context of Hamilton's principle?

As I tried to explain, only differences of $S$ between two paths of same boundary conditions matter. Look at what happens to the simple example

Ah, I think I see it now. If we let $\delta L = 0$, i.e. no transformation is done to either the Lagrangian or the EOMs, we obviously get $\delta S = 0$. However, if we perform, like in your example, a translation on the EOMs, they stay invariant despite the Lagrangian changing due to its dependence on $q$. This causes $\delta L \neq 0$ thus $\delta S \neq 0$, but the same EOMs still pop out. I now see why the book motivates the fact that restricting $\delta L = 0$ was too stringent as a prelude to Noether's theorem because $L$ can change while the EOMs stay invariant.
